# Struts 2 - How to map a wildcard-matched method to an exception?

Tags: java, exception, struts2

I'm working with Struts2. Here's a snippet of my struts.xml file:

```
<action name="*test" class="fend.config.TestAction" method="{1}">
            <exception-mapping result="fail" exception="java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException"/>
            <result name="success">/registerCrisis.jsp</result>
            <result name="dummy">/dummy.jsp</result>
            <result name="fail">error.jsp</result>
            <interceptor-ref name="configStack"/>
        </action>
```

When I run the application like: http://localhost:8080/appContext/viewtest.action struts calls the view method in the TestAction class. I the view method I put code that generates a **java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException** just for testing purpose.

What I intended was to redirect to the result named fail, so that error.jsp is showned. But it's not redirecting to the page. What I've missed?

Thank you.

Comment: Just an errata here, I've mistyped the fail result on the snippet. Where you read error.jsp is /error.jsp.

Comment: If you return success does it render the registerCrisis.jsp page? In other words, are you sure the problem is with `<exception-mapping>`, and not with `<result>` ?

Comment: If it return success it renders registerCrisis.jsp. But when I get an UnsupportedOperationException I don't know what struts returns, but its rendering registerCrisis.jsp. I thought that with the mapped exception being thrown struts would render the error.jsp page. If for instance, I get the same exception in the execute method it renders error.jsp correctly.

Comment: Can you show us your  `<exception-mapping>` fragment in your struts.xml ? Did you map every exception to a 'fail' result?

Comment: @leonbloy I just added this <exception-mapping> in the xml, just this one inner to this action.

Comment: and... ? It does now work?  i see you are using a special interceptor stack. Something particular there?

Answer (score 0):

You can create another action under your exist action , this may allow the rest of paths (errors path) to redirect another action , this may allow the rest of paths (errors path) to redirect another page.

```
<action name="*test" class="fend.config.TestAction" method="{1}">

        <result name="success">/registerCrisis.jsp</result>
        <result name="dummy">/dummy.jsp</result>
        <result name="fail">error.jsp</result>
        <interceptor-ref name="configStack"/>
    </action>

<!-- SOLUTION, ADD THIS-->

    <action name="*" method="myErrorMethod" class="fend.config.TestAction">
        <result type="redirectAction">
            <param name="namespace">/myErrorPath</param>
            <param name="actionName">myErrorMethodtest</param><!--*test (if your error method has wildcard) -->
        </result>
    </action>
```